# PHP login page with redirection to different pages based on user access level

Tags: php, session, redirect, authentication

How can i send multiple sessions variables to a page?

For example i have a login.php page which verifies a user's email and password and access level (admin, teacher, student) stored in database and grants access accordingly to student.php, admin.php, faculty.php

On the student.php, admin.php and faculty.php pages i have set session blocks which check the user level received from previous pages and allows or denies access accordingly.

So far this works fine, however now i would like to create specific page for each user for which i need to check user level (admin, user, faculty > which is already being checked ) + their specific user id or email using which i could generate specific content catered to them..

**So getting back to my question, is there a way to send multiple variables to a page**??

**Or more importantly, if im not thinking in the right track is there a better way of doing this?**

Many thanks,

Comment: You already check for their level, why not put different pages behind those checks? Or is there something else? It might help to show some of the relevant code if possible.

Comment: Don’t forget to not just check authorization for the redirect but also on the different pages themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Simply declare `$_SESSION` as an array.

```
$_SESSION["uid"] //User ID (mail whatever)
$_SESSION["access"] //Admin, student, teacher etc.
```

**[Manual Reference](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)**

Comment: I tried that, but on the destination pages > i don't think they are receiving it.. unless im doing something wrong.. here is the code on login.php page

Comment: if (($role == 'admin') && ($status == 'active')) {
   // Set username session variable
   $_SESSION['role'] = $role;
   $_SESSION['fname'] = $fname;
   $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
   // Jump to secured page
   header('Location: securedpage.php');
   }
   
   else if (($role == 'student') && ($status == 'active'))  {
   // Set username session variable
   $_SESSION['role'] = $role;
   $_SESSION['fname'] = $fname;
   $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
   // Jump to secured page
   header('Location: usrsecuredpage.php');
   }

Comment: Make sure you are using `start_session()` appropriately and before any output is sent. Also, `$role` and `$status` might not be defined on a new page, put them in the array as well (`$_SESSION['role']`). On a last note, line-breaks don't work on comments, so make sure to use `` to signify code in comments :)

Comment: thanks for the help, actually for some stupid reason i was trying to receive session variable on destination page like this $_SESSION['fname'] =$fname; instead of just $_SESSION['fname']; ... totaly newb :P

Comment: just to clarify something, is using sessions the best way to create user specific page ?? or is there another better method??

Answer (score 0):

> is using sessions the best way to create user specific page ??

Sessions (and better with a secure cookie) are only good for re-identifying the requesting user.

Never give the role to the client-side. The application should always check the role of a user before delivering a page or executing requests. You should strictly avoid to pass values to the client-side which can be manipulated to gain higher rights or to let the user see or manipulate the data of another user.